# If $V$ is a vector space, that what is $V^\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: notation

Notation question (I believe the notes that I'm reading uses pretty common notation):

Let $V $ be a vector space over a field $K$. What is $V^\mathbb{N}$? Is it a vector space of infinite dimensions? What are the elements of $V^\mathbb{N}$? Are they infinite length tuples?

Comment: BTW I'd have preferred to ask this question on chat.math.stackexchange.com but it's not setup yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, this notation is ambiguous (edit: but maybe I'm wrong).  It could mean two things: it could mean the space of functions $\mathbb{N} \to V$, which is a vector space in the obvious way.  This is the countable product in the category of vector spaces.  This vector space is very large; in particular, it has uncountable dimension and it is *not* spanned by the functions $e_i$ which are equal to $1$ at $i$ and equal to $0$ elsewhere.

Or it could mean the space of functions $\mathbb{N} \to V$ which are zero except at finitely many places, which is also a vector space in the obvious way, but countable-dimensional, and this is the vector space spanned by the $e_i$.  This is the countable *coproduct* in the category of vector spaces.  (Note that it is not necessary to distinguish between finite products and finite coproducts because they are the same.)

If I had to guess, I would guess that it means the former.  Can you give a link to the notes?  It might be possible to figure out which one is meant from context.

Comment: Unfortunately the notes are under protected access within my campus :[ (edit:oops return) Thanks. I check both function spaces and infer which is consistent with the notes.

Comment: I would guess the former too. Most of the time I see the notation $V^\mathbb{N}$ it means "the space of sequences taking values in $V$".

Comment: @Qiaochu: I think I never saw the notation $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ for the coproduct in vector spaces. Do you remember any place where you found it?

Comment: @Nuno: maybe I'm worrying about nothing.  But textbooks generally don't stress that direct product and direct sum aren't the same thing in general.

Comment: @Qiaochu: I don't think $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ is used for the coproduct, though I *have* seen $V^{(\mathbb{N})}$ for the elements of $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ of finite support...

Comment: @Qiaochu: Could you elaborate on why the former has uncountable dimension?

Comment: @Rahul: $V^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the dual of the latter. Here is Bill Dubuque's proof that for infinite dimensional $W$, the dimension of the dual is $|F|^{\dim(W)}$: http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/82792c829f7fe139. Applied to this case, since the dimension of $W$ is $\aleph_0$, the dimension of the dual is uncountable.

Comment: @Rahul Narain: let e_i : V^N to V denote the evaluation homomorphism at the ith place and let v_1, v_2, ... be a sequence of elements of V^N.  Let n_j be the smallest index at which e_{n_j}(v_j) is nonzero.  WLOG this sequence is increasing (by taking suitable linear combinations).  Then construct w as follows: pick e_1(w), ... e_{n_1+1}(w) so that w is not in span{v_1}, pick e_{n_1+2}(w), ... e_{n_2+1}(w) so that w is not in span{v_1, v_2}, etc.  Then w is not in the span of the v_i.  (Of course one needs the hypothesis that K is infinite.)

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks for the link. I'm not very well-versed in infinite-dimensional vector spaces, so it will take me a while to digest that proof. @Qiaochu: Ah, I see; I was forgetting that the span is composed of linear combinations, which by definition involve only *finitely* many vectors.

Answer (score 1):

It would be the vector space consisting of an infinite product V × V × ... of copies of V.

More generally: for two sets A and B, A<sup>B</sup> often denotes the set of functions *f* : B → A. (The only exception I'm aware of is when the sets A and B happen to be ordinals, in set theory; then a different notion of exponentiation is often used.)

How are these two concepts related? Well: as a vector space, V is also a set of vectors. And so a function *f* : ℕ → V is essentially a block-vector description of a vector **v** = (*f*(0), *f*(1), ...) ∈ V × V × ... .

Comment: surely in the beginning of the second paragraph you meant $f:B\to A$.

Comment: @Willie Wong: that's right, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think of it as the set of sequences of elements of $V$, i.e.

$$ V^\mathbb{N} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty V.$$

But I don't think there is a really nice description. In the case where $V$ is finite-dimensional, it'd just be $K^\mathbb{N}$ in a clever (and non-canonically isomorphic) disguise, but if $V$ were to be infinite-dimensional, $V^\mathbb{N}$ could be rather ugly. E.g. $\ell_1^\mathbb{N}$: sequences of absolutely summable sequences. Then a sequence of sequences would converge to a sequence iff it converged coordinatewise. Complicated and very confusing.

Following Munkres' "Topology", I prefer to use $V^\infty$ for set of sequences in $V$ for which only finitely many elements are nonzero, i.e.

$$V^\infty = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty V = \left\lbrace (v_n) \in V^\mathbb{N} \;{\large\mid}\; \text{$v_n = 0$ from some index onwards}\right\rbrace. $$